# Datepicker and Calendar example for calculating Day diffrence and shows output accordingly

Tags: android, datepicker, calendar

Following is my code. According to my APp, I can enter From DAte and ToDAte by clicking respective buttons. But after selecting dates from datepicker dialog, i have to find the diffrence between days. And then calculate the total cost. But there's something wrong with my code, due to which my FromDate and ToDate takes the same date and therefore shows the total cost as zero only. I am new to the Android. Please help me to solve this problem.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tv_rentcarheading, tv_costresult;
Button btndateFrom, btndateTo, btncalculate;
int CurrentYear1, CurrentMonth1, CurrentDay1, CurrentYear2, CurrentMonth2, CurrentDay2;
final int rent = 150;
static final int dialog_id1 = 0, dialog_id2 = 0;
long n, totalcost;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv_rentcarheading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_rentcar);
    tv_costresult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
    btndateFrom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_fromdate);
    btndateTo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_todate);
    btncalculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_result);

    tv_costresult.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();

    CurrentYear1 = calendar1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    CurrentMonth1 = calendar1.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    CurrentDay1 = calendar1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    CurrentYear2 = calendar2.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    CurrentMonth2 = calendar2.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    CurrentDay2 = calendar2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


    showDialogOnButtonClick();

    calendar1.set(CurrentYear1, CurrentMonth1, CurrentDay1);
    calendar2.set(CurrentYear2, CurrentMonth2, CurrentDay2);

    n = (calendar2.getTimeInMillis() - calendar1.getTimeInMillis() );
    totalcost = n * rent;

    btncalculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            totalcost = n * rent;
            tv_costresult.setText("The Cost of car from " +CurrentMonth1+"/"+CurrentDay1+"/"+CurrentYear1+" to "+CurrentMonth1+"/"+CurrentDay1+"/"+CurrentYear1+" is "+totalcost);
            tv_costresult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}


public void showDialogOnButtonClick()
{
    btndateFrom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(dialog_id1);
        }
    });

    btndateTo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(dialog_id2);
        }
    });
}


@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    if(id == dialog_id1)
        return new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, setDateListener1, CurrentYear1, CurrentMonth1, CurrentDay1);


    if(id == dialog_id2)
        return new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, setDateListener2, CurrentYear2, CurrentMonth2, CurrentDay2);


    else
        return null;
}


private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener setDateListener1 = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)
    {
        CurrentYear1 = year;
        CurrentMonth1 = month + 1;
        CurrentDay1 = dayOfMonth;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "From Date is " + CurrentMonth1 +"/" + CurrentDay1+ "/" + CurrentYear1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
    }
};


private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener setDateListener2 = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)
    {
        CurrentYear2 = year;
        CurrentMonth2 = month +1;
        CurrentDay2 = dayOfMonth;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "From Date is " + CurrentMonth2 +"/" + CurrentDay2+ "/" + CurrentYear2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
    }
};
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It is showing zero as a result because you are setting `calendar1` and `calendar2` outside of the `btncalculate` onclicklistener. Moverover, you need to decrement `CurrentMonth1` and `CurrentMonth2` before setting them to calendars.

Move this portion of code from `onCreate` to inside of the `btncalculate.setOnClickListener(...)`

```
CurrentMonth1 = CurrentMonth1 - 1;
CurrentMonth2 = CurrentMonth2 - 1;
calendar1.set(CurrentYear1, CurrentMonth1, CurrentDay1);
calendar2.set(CurrentYear2, CurrentMonth2, CurrentDay2);

n = (calendar2.getTimeInMillis() - calendar1.getTimeInMillis() );
n = n / ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 );
totalcost = n * rent;
```

Comment: @RamMalhotra was my answer helpful for you? Did you try it?